# super method undefined in class declaration

Tags: javascript, class, new-operator, extends, super

**TL;DR** - *The super keyword in my class declaration is sometimes (but not always) undefined. How/why?*

I have the following class declaration extending `Array` used for search result data from an API:

```
class SearchResult extends Array {
  constructor(resultArray) {
    super(...resultArray);
  }

  static createFromApiData(apiData) {
    const resultArray = apiData.filter(...).map(...);
    return new SearchResult(resultArray);
  }

  ...otherMethods

}
```

In my app this is initially called immediately on receiving the response from the API, like below:

```
apiCall().then((res) => {
  const searchResults = SearchResult.createFromApiData(res.data);
});
```

Creating a new `SearchResult` instance using this static method works correctly, returning what I want.

However, later in my app I need to create a `SearchResult` instance again, this time there is no need for an API call as I already have the `resultArray` data stored in a database. Therefore the second time around I try to create the instance of `SearchResult` using the `new` keyword like below:

```
const searchResults = new SearchResult(resultArray);
```

This time, using the `new` keyword the instance creation fails throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function at new SearchResult
```

I know `undefined` in this context is referring to the `super` keyword but I can not understand why this is the case? How can the instance creation behaviour vary in these two cases? How can I fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

I've investigated further and found the following. My initial issue was caused because I was saving my custom `SearchResult` class instance to the database (*dynamodb*). Although `SearchResult` extended array, *ddb* saved it as a basic object, so on retrieval of the data from the database it came in basic object, not array form. This then threw an error when I attempted to spread the object inside inside the `super` function.

I resolved this by spreading my class instance in a new array when saving it to *ddb*:

```
db.save([...searchResults]);
```

This returned an array after database recall and could be successfully spread inside the `super` call.

However, this has lead to a new issue. Immediately after creating the new `SearchResult` instance I call a the following custom method on it:

```
nextItem() {
  this.splice(0, 1);
  return this[0];
}
```

This method then again calls `super` to access the `splice` method on `Array`. However, once again this fails throwing the same error as before:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "undefined is not a function",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "new SearchResult",
    "SearchResult.splice",
    "SearchResult.nextRecipe"
}
```

Once again this is referring to the spread operation inside `super`. This time `super` is being passed the number `1` as its sole argument. Where is is this `1` coming from and how can I fix it?

---

**UPDATE 2**

After updating the class method to us `shift` instead of `splice` the method now works correctly without errors. My problem is now effectively solved, however I would still appreciate insight on what the issue of `super` being called with `1` was about with `splice`. Why would these two array methods behave differently in this context.

```
nextItem() {
  return this.shift();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is really caused by `super()` call? Or is it just "in that line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know undefined in this context is referring to the super keyword but I can not understand why this is the case?

Probably not. `super` refers to the internal unchangeable [[HomeObject]] property of the class, that gets set when the class gets declared, you can't modify that, you can only rewrite the class itself, e.g.:

```
 SearchResult = function() { undefined(); }
```

But I guess you don't do that.

But where does the error come from?

Well there are two things happening in that line:

```
 super(...resultArray);
```

One is the `super()` call and the other one is the spreading of the `resultArray`, which will create and consume an iterator of the `resultArray` which is barely equal to:

```
 resultArray[Symbol.iterator]()
```

and if the iterator does not exist (because you accidently passed a non array to the constructor) it fails, saying that the iterator can't be called:

```
 var resultArray = {};

 resultArray[Symbol.iterator]()
 // equals:
 undefined()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you that makes sense! As you said in your comment, I don't know for certain that it is `super` just the line the error was on, so it could be the spread. I'll check to make sure I am actually passing an array.

Comment: I've tested the `resultArray` data that is passed when creating the second instance, you were correct that this was the issue. I am passing the correct data, however the datatype is wrong. It is a conventional object with numeric keys, rather than an actual array (logging it returns this `{ '0': {...}, '1': {...} }` instead of this `[{...}, {...}]`). I now just need to identify why the datatype is changing and how I can fix that.

Comment: I solved the original `super` call/spread issue based on your comment, however this has led to an immediate repeat of the same problem once the class instance is created. I've added an update above with the details.

Comment: @josh actually that is a completely new question